# Loading instance of django model into modelform

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

After a long time of being able to always find my answers on here, I now need to actually ask my first question...

I'm working on a form which takes an instance of a modal, loads it in there (is what it should do) after which the user can edit the contents and resave the thing.

I have been trying for hours now to load this initial instance into my form. This form is a customized Modelform originating from the Child model, which can be found using the following url: `path("children_overview/details/<int:child>/edit", ChildEdit, name="Child_Edit"),` :

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms.widgets import Select
from django.db.models import Q
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

import datetime
import re

from apps.childreg.models import Parents, Child, Child_Reg_Info, Child

class Child(models.Model):
    male = "MAN"
    female = "WOMAN"

    SEXES=[(male, _('male')),(female, _('female'))]

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ExternalId = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    ChildId = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    FirstName = models.CharField(_('childs first name'), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    LastName = models.CharField(_('childs last name'), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    FullName = models.CharField(_('childs full name'), max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    DateOfBirth = models.DateField(_('date of birth'), blank=True, null=True)
    Location = models.ForeignKey(Location, verbose_name=_('location of registration'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Nation = models.ForeignKey(Nation, verbose_name=_('country of registration'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Parents = models.ForeignKey(Parents, verbose_name=_('parents of the child'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Sex = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=SEXES, verbose_name=_('sex of the child'), null=True, blank=True)
    Born = models.BooleanField(_('Has the child been born?'), default=False)
    Died = models.BooleanField(_("Has the child passed away?"), default=False)

    def stridentifier(self):
        try:
            name = str(self.ExternalId)[13:] + " - " + self.FullName
            return name
        except:
            pass
        name = str(self.ExternalId)[13:] + " - " + str(_("Parents "))
        if self.Parents.FatherFirstName == None:
            return name + self.Parents.MotherFirstName + " " + self.Parents.MotherLastName
        if self.Parents.FatherLastName == None:
            return name + self.Parents.MotherFirstName + " " + self.Parents.MotherLastName
        return name + self.Parents.MotherFirstName + " " + self.Parents.MotherLastName + " & " + self.Parents.FatherFirstName + " " + self.Parents.FatherLastName

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.FullName = self.FirstName + " " + self.LastName
        except:
            self.FullName = None
        super(Child, self).save()

        def __str__(self):
            name = Child.stridentifier(self)
            return name

    @receiver(post_save)
    def post_save(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
        if created:
            if isinstance(instance, Child):
                instance.ExternalId = CreateID(instance)
                instance.ChildId = ("%06d"%instance.pk)[-6:]
                super(Child, instance).save()
        else:
            pass

    def __str__(self):
        name = Child.stridentifier(self)
        return name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('child')
        verbose_name_plural = _('children')
```

The modelform with slight alterations:

```
class ChildForm(ModelForm, forms.Form):

    DateOfBirth = forms.DateField(widget=DateSelectorWidget())

    class Meta:
        model = Child
        exclude = ["ChildId", "ExternalId", "ChildID", "Location", "Nation", "FullName", "Parents", "Died"]


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            field_name = re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", field)
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control', })#'placeholder': field_name})
```

And the issue of the entire thing, the view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
import datetime

from apps.childreg.forms import NewParentForm, ExParentForm, ParentTypeForm, ChildForm, ChildExtendedForm
from apps.childreg.models import Parents, Child
import algorithms.AccessValidation as AccessValidation

@login_required()
def ChildEdit(request, child):
    ChildInstance = get_object_or_404(Child, pk=child)
    FormEditChild = ChildForm(request.POST, instance=ChildInstance)
    if AccessValidation.Checkin(request, ChildInstance)
        if request.method == 'POST':
           FormEditChild = ChildForm(request.POST, instance=ChildInstance)
    return render(request, "childreg/edit.html", {
    "FormEditChild": FormEditChild,
    "child": ChildInstance,
    })
```

I omitted the entire resaving process since that isn't really of importance. The initial data first needs to be loaded into the form that is rendered in the webbrowser.

Things I already tested myself:

1. Does django actually parse the instance at all?

   Yes, my insanely professional inline print statement found that the code has the  needed ChildInstance loaded into this variable.
2. Are the placeholder texts problematic (I got desperate):

   Nope, commenting everything out doesn't really make a difference
3. Moving around the FormEditChild variable containing the form below the `request.method == "POST"` if statement

   Nope...
4. Omitting the `request.POST` statement from `ChildForm(request.POST, instance=ChildInstance)`

   Still a hard no unfortunately

Thanks in advance for reading this and a really big thanks for providing me with any help at all!

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out myself:

thanks to: https://projectsplaza.com/add-and-update-data-with-modelform-in-django-3/

When you make a view containing an instance of a model, you first need to load that form with the instance, without the request.POST keyword in the form class function.

so the view should be something like this

```
@login_required()
def ChildEdit(request, child):
    ChildInstance = get_object_or_404(Child, pk=child)
    if AccessValidation.Checkin(request, ChildInstance):
        FormEditChild = ChildForm(instance=ChildInstance)
        FormEditChildExt = ChildExtendedForm(instance=get_object_or_404(Child_Reg_Info, ChildElaboration=ChildInstance))
        if request.method == 'POST':
            FormEditChild = ChildForm(request.POST, instance=ChildInstance)
            FormEditChildExt = ChildExtendedForm(request.POST, instance=Child_Reg_Info.get_object_or_404(ChildElaboration=ChildInstance))
            if FormEditChild.is_valid():
                FormEditChild.save(commit=False)
#               .....
                FormEditChild.save()
        return render(request, "childreg/edit.html", {
        "FormEditChild": FormEditChild,
        "FormEditChildExt": FormEditChildExt,
        "child": ChildInstance,
        })
    return redirect(AccessValidation.CheckinTLocation)
```

When you initially load the forms, omit the request.POST and only apply this in the form function after the `if request.method == 'POST'` statement has been applied. This way you render the form with the initial data at first without needing post data that does not exist yet. When the user posts the data aka: `request.method == 'POST'` the form post data is loaded and saved in this case.